# How to make order-independent assertions on Flux output?

Tags: unit-testing, project-reactor

I have a [test case for a Flux from Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing) roughly like this:

```java
testMultipleChunks(StepVerifier.FirstStep<Chunk> verifier, Chunk chunk1, Chunk chunk2) {
    verifier.then(() -> {
        worker.add(chunk1);
        worker.add(chunk2);
        worker.update();
    })
    .expectNext(chunk1, chunk2)
    .verifyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
```

Thing is, my worker is encouraged to parallelize the work, which means the order of the output is undefined. `chunk2, chunk1` would be equally valid.

How can I make assertions on the output in an order-independent way?

Properties I care about:

- every element in the expected set is present
- there are no *unexpected* elements
- there are no extra (duplicate) events

I tried this:

```java
testMultipleChunks(StepVerifier.FirstStep<Chunk> verifier, Chunk chunk1, Chunk chunk2) {
    Set<Chunk> expectedOutput = Set.of(chunk1, chunk2);
    verifier.then(() -> {
        worker.add(chunk1);
        worker.add(chunk2);
        worker.update();
    })
   .recordWith(HashSet::new)
   .expectNextCount(expectedOutput.size())
   .expectRecordedMatches(expectedOutput::equals)
   .verifyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
```

While I think that makes the assertions I want, it took a terrible dive in readability. A clear one-line, one-method assertion was replaced with *four* lines with a lot of extra punctuation.

`expectedRecordedMatches` is also horribly uninformative when it fails, saying only “expected collection predicate match” without giving any information about what the expectation is or how close the result was.

What's a clearer way to write this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StepVerifier` is not a good fit for that because it verifies each signal as it gets emitted, and materialize an expected order for asynchronous signals, by design.

It is especially tricky because (it seems) your publisher under test doesn't clearly complete.

If it was completing after N elements (N being the expected amount here), I'd change the publisher passed to `StepVerifier.create` from `flux` to `flux.collectList()`. That way, you get a `List` view of the `onNext` and you can assert the list as you see fit (eg. using AssertJ, which I recommend).

One alternative in recent versions of Reactor is the `TestSubscriber`, which can be used to drive `request` and `cancel()` without any particular opinion on blocking or on when to perform the assertions. Instead, it internally stores the events it sees (`onNext` go into a `List`, `onComplete` and `onError` are stored as a terminal `Signal`...) and you can access these for arbitrary assertions.

Comment: Ok, makes sense about StepVerifier. I've successfully switched to using TestSubscriber in order to be able to access the values even though it ends with TimeoutException. It works, but still feels like I'm over-complicating things.

Comment: I also attempted to use `.buffer(duration, scheduler).next()` to solve the "publisher does not complete" problem, but waiting on that `next` just timed out. Might have used the wrong scheduler somewhere, dunno.